# Where can I find source of unhook function used in STL implementation provided with g++

Tags: c++, stl, implementation

It is used in /usr/include/c++/4.3/stl_list.h on my system (current Ubuntu).

Comment: No need to downvote. I was sure that STL list was only include based library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://gcc.gnu.org/

Have a look at the Download or "Live" Sources sections.